# Mixing trait and base class with same method

Tags: scala, inheritance, traits, base-class

Can I safely inherit both a trait and a base class which share the same method?

Like:

```
trait MyTrait {
   def getValue:String
}

class SomeClass {
   def getValue:String = [concrete implementation]
}
```

then:

```
class MyClass extends SomeClass with MyTrait
```

The reason to do this is I'd like to use it in another (abstract) class, which defines the required API only via the `MyTrait` trait, and I cannot have `SomeClass` inherit this trait directly (because its from another unrelated library).

```
abstract class AbstractOtherClass {
   val mainObject:MyTrait
}
```

and then the concrete implementation of that class:

```
class OtherClass extends AbstractOtherClass {
   val mainObject:MyTrait = new MyClass

   def something = {
      println(mainObject.getValue)  // shall call SomeClass.getValue
   }
}
```

---

**Solution**
After SergGr's suggestion I ended up with a solution like this:

```
abstract class AbstractOtherClass {
   def getValue:String
}

class OtherClass extends AbstractOtherClass {
   val mainObject:SomeClass = ...

   def getValue:String = mainObject.getValue
}
```

Comment: ~I just pasted all your snippets in a **Scala _2.12.8_** shell and it all worked... So, are you having any specific problem with this?, maybe your real code is more complex and does not compiles?~ - Nevermind, I just read that your question is if this is safe to do... uhm, sorry I'm not sure if I know enough about Scala to answer that.

Comment: My code also works with this. I'd just like to know if this works by chance or if it maybe is really bad design.
My concerns are mainly that in `OtherClass` I am using a reference to the `MyTrait` trait, which must "forward" the method access to `SomeClass` however, just because the reference is an instance of `MyClass`, which inherits both the trait and the class.
I would have expected that this fails, because `mainObject` tries to call `getValue`  from `MyTrait` instead of `SomeClass`, because those two are not directly related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there are two different questions here

1. Does this work merely by an accident?
2. It this a good design?

As long as your `trait` has only declaration of the method but no implementation, it works by design. This is one of the unusual but expected usage pattern. If several `trait`s or a `trait` and a `class` have implementations of the same method, there is still an explicitly specified logic of [linearization](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/05-classes-and-objects.html#class-linearization) that specifies how to resolve the conflicts but I'd say that in most cases relying on that is a bad design.

The thing you are trying to do looks like an [adapter pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) to me and I'd say that from the design point of view it is better to implement it using object composition rather than inheritance:

```
trait MyTrait {
   def getValue:String
}

class SomeClassWrapper(delegate: SomeClass) extends MyTrait {
    override def getValue:String = delegate.getValue       
}
```

Doing it this way you don't bind your API to the implementation of the library. For example you can rename the method to `getAbcValue` value if this makes more sense in your context. Or if you at some point find another library that does the same work better but that has a different name for such method (like `calculateValue`), you have to create just another wrapper class and don't have to change all the `getValue` calls to `calculateValue` calls.

Comment: Sounds good. I was able to rework the solution a bit to avoid this pattern but achieve the same. In fact it turned out that I didn't exactly need the `val mainObject:MyTrait` in `AbstractOtherClass`, but instead relayed it (as you also suggested) by introducing a `def getValue` in `AbstractOtherClass`. This way, `OtherClass` can directly use `SomeClass` on its own, and the trait becomes useless.